# Why Symfony erases password during the creation of a new user related entity?

Tags: symfony

When Symfony makes an insert (for the creation of a new entity) the password of the user that makes this request is cleared.

I have an entity that has the *User* ID as foreign key, that is mapped as a `ManyToOne` relation for Doctrine.

I observed that behind the scenes, on each `persist()` request, the method [eraseCredentials()](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html#method_eraseCredentials) is constantly recalled:

> public **eraseCredentials**()
>
> Removes sensitive data from the user.
>
> This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like the plain-text password is stored on this object.

This method is defined as part of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`. Now, someone suggests me to not implement this method (leave it blank), but I think this is not the best way to avoid this behaviour.

<kbd>**User entity**</kbd>

```
public function eraseCredentials() {
  $this->password = false;
}
```

<kbd>**Controller newAction**</kbd>

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      // Add default info for ticketreply creation
      $dt = new \DateTime();
      $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
      $ticket = $em->getRepository('SupportBundle:Ticket')->find($tid);
      $ticketReply
        ->setTicket($ticket)
        ->setAuthor($user)
        ->setCreationDate($dt)
      ;
      $em->persist($ticketReply);
      $em->flush();
```

<kbd>dev.log</kbd>

```
[2016-02-18 15:16:58] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_default"} []
[2016-02-18 15:16:58] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"MYUSER","provider":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\User\\ChainUserProvider"} []
[2016-02-18 15:16:58] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE account SET password = ? WHERE id = ? [false,1] []
```

I'm using **Symfony 2.8.2**

#### Why is this happening? Why it keeps calling the eraseCredentials() method?

**EDIT**

What is more, I want to comprehend **when** the `eraseCredentials()` is executed. Under what conditions?

Comment: As pointed out by *elnur* on #symfony IRC channel, maybe the cause could be that I'm using a single field for both encrypted and plain password. To be honest, at the moment, **I have only a plain password**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found an explanation. This behaviour continues happening because I store the user's password, for debugging reasons, in a single field. Moreover, I'm persisting it on the database.

The answer is on the *firing events* of `eraseCredentials()` method. So, as stated by *elnur* on Symfony IRC channel, it makes sense when you keep sensitive information like plaintext password **along** with an encoded password.

> < elnur> For instance, the user object gets serialized into session.
>   If the plainpassword gets serialized and malicious users get access to sessions, they'll get password.

The solution is:

1. using only a plain-text password and **not** implementing/overloading `UserInterface->eraseCredentials()` (default blank implementation);
2. using a plain-password **and** an encrypted password field, implementing the `eraseCredentials()` method to be sure to clean the sensitive information of the user.